# CSS Animation Not Showing Up in DevTools Animation Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

It appears that CSS animations implemented with JS won't show up in the Animations tab of the Developer Tools.

For example, check out the YouTube "mute" button. There is no keyframes or animation details defined in the CSS files.

The CSS animation seems to be performed by a JS method that calls the CSS "translate" function of the "path" elements within the SVG element. However, it was very difficult to follow the code, so I wasn't able to replicate the CSS animation.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: it probably uses [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is not supported at the moment, check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations/#overview).

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo. I remember seeing that method being called. I'll look into "requestAnimationFrame."

Comment: once i'm sure of it, i will post an awnser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Chrome DevTools Animations Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), it states that [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is not supported at the moment.

My main guess is that some animations *(the translation ones)* are being invoked from a javascrit method that uses `requestAnimationFrame` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo. I've broken my original question into two questions. If you happen to know how to replicate CSS animations that are implemented with requestAnimationFrame, the second question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218394/how-to-replicate-css-animations-implemented-using-requestanimationframe